# RSpec 2 and 3 How to create a helper that will generate a bunch of examples?

Tags: ruby, json, rspec

I'm trying to create helper to test JSON responses in uniform and nice way.

For more descriptive and specific failures I want to generate one example per JSON atom.

Example syntax:

```
RSpec.describe "some JSON API View" do

  setup_objects

  before { render }

  describe "response" do

    subject { rendered }

    it_conforms_to_json(
      id: 27,
      email: "john.smith@example.com",
      name: "John",
      profile_description: %r{professional specialist},
      nested: {
        id: 37,
        status: "rejected"
      }
    )

  end

end
```

So this snippet will be an equivalent to:

```
RSpec.describe "some JSON API View" do

  setup_objects

  before { render }

  describe "response" do

    subject { rendered }

    it 'has equal value at object["id"]' do
      expect(subject["id"]).to eq(27)
    end

    it 'has equal value at object["email"]' do
      expect(subject["email"]).to eq("john.smith@example.com")
    end

    it 'has equal value at object["name"]' do
      expect(subject["name"]).to eq("John")
    end

    it 'has matching value at object["profile_description"]' do
      expect(subject["profile_description"]).to match(%r{professional specialist})
    end

    it 'has equal value at object["nested"]["id"]' do
      expect(subject["nested"]["id"]).to eq(37)
    end

    it 'has equal value at object["nested"]["status"]' do
      expect(subject["nested"]["status"]).to eq("rejected")
    end

  end

end
```

I was able to achieve that easily with this snippet:

```
module JsonHelper
  extend self

  def it_conforms_to_json(json)
    generate_examples_for(json)
  end

  private

  def generate_examples_for(json, opts)
    with_prefix = opts.fetch(:with_prefix, [])

    if json.is_a?(Hash)

      json.each do |key, new_json|
        new_prefix = with_prefix + [key.to_s]
        generate_examples_for(new_json, opts.merge(with_prefix: new_prefix))
      end

    elsif json.is_a?(Array)

      raise NotImplemented.new("Arrays are not allowed yet")

    elsif json.is_a?(String) || json.is_a?(Numeric)

      it "is expected to have equal value at json[\"#{with_prefix.join('"]["')}\"]" do
        value = JSON.parse(subject)
        with_prefix.each { |key| value = value[key.to_s] }
        expect(value).to eq(json)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

And just enabling it by extending it: `rspec_config.extend JsonHelper`

Obvious problem starts when you think about pretty failure messages:

- They show backtrace including location of `it "is expected...bla-bla-bla`
- They exclude location of `it_conforms_to_json(...)` call

First is fixable by adding backtrace exclusion/clean pattern, but it results in a full backtrace because everything is filtered.

Second and previous is fixable by wrapping `expect` statement in `begin..rescue`, mangling with backtrace by prepending it with `file_path:line` of `it_conforms_to_json(...)` call and re-raising modified exception.

After first 2 problems are being resolved, the new one arises:

- "Unable to find matching line from the backtrace"

Suspected method is `find_first_non_rspec_line` (or something similar), that finds first line in a backtrace of `it` call (not exception backtrace) by applying default rspec exclusion regex'es.

It is fixable by mangling with RSpec internals, i.e.:

- For rspec 2: monkey patch method that applies this regex'es
- For rspec 3: undefine constant `LIB_REGEX` and define it again adding this helper files to this regex
- For rspec 3 (recent minor/patch versions): the same, but with `IGNORE_REGEX`

Code of this fixup becomes shitty and unreadable, and it will be hell to maintain, because it depends on rspec inner implementation, that can change from minor/patch version to version. Who interested in reading this ugly thing [here](https://github.com/waterlink/rspec-json_expectations/blob/49b1eabf03afa6af95f727d1c752c0b4c760682f/lib/rspec/json_expectations/exclusion.rb)

More that that, it acts differently for rspec 2 and rspec 3.

rspec 2, perfectly what is required:

```
    Failures:

    1) A json response is expected to have equal value at json["id"]
       Failure/Error: it_conforms_to_json(

         expected: 37
              got: 25

         (compared using ==)
       # ./spec/simple_with_fail_spec.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'

    2) A json response is expected to have equal value at json["name"]
       Failure/Error: it_conforms_to_json(

         expected: "Smith"
              got: "John"

         (compared using ==)
       # ./spec/simple_with_fail_spec.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

rspec 3, slightly off, but still acceptable:

Failures:

```
    1) A json response is expected to have equal value at json["id"]
       Failure/Error: expect(value).to eq(json)

         expected: 37
              got: 25

         (compared using ==)
       # ./spec/simple_with_fail_spec.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
       # ./lib/rspec/json_expectations/expectations.rb:32:in `block in generate_examples_for'

    2) A json response is expected to have equal value at json["name"]
       Failure/Error: expect(value).to eq(json)

         expected: "Smith"
              got: "John"

         (compared using ==)
       # ./spec/simple_with_fail_spec.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
       # ./lib/rspec/json_expectations/expectations.rb:32:in `block in generate_examples_for'
```

So here are the questions:

- **Is there any built-in public-API means of achieving it?**
- **It seems I have problems with naming here, it is not expectations, but what...?**

Comment: The answer to your second question is "custom matchers" - google that and you'll find help on writing these nicely.

Comment: Thanks @TarynEast . But here I wanted to generate a bunch of examples (`it` statements) for each atomic part of JSON. Which allow in case of error it to show concrete failed JSON paths, not the whole JSON. But to me it seems to be possible to achieve through custom logic in `failure_message` block.

Comment: @TarynEast Hey, if you want to you can form an example and put it as an answer, just let me know if you want to do that, otherwise I will do that myself once I have some free time, so that it will help somebody in the future.

Comment: thanks. If you have a solution - it'd be great for you to post it. I just have an inkling of how I'd begin to think one up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it is a bit ugly now (first iteration, though), but works. No mangling with RSpec internals, using only public RSpec API, with nice error messages, without even cleaning a backtrace:

```
module RSpec
  module JsonExpectations
    class JsonTraverser
      def self.traverse(errors, expected, actual, prefix=[])
        if expected.is_a?(Hash)

          expected.map do |key, value|
            new_prefix = prefix + [key]
            if actual.has_key?("#{key}")
              traverse(errors, value, actual["#{key}"], new_prefix)
            else
              errors[new_prefix.join("/")] = :no_key
              false
            end
          end.all?

        elsif expected.is_a?(String) || expected.is_a?(Numeric)

          if actual == expected
            true
          else
            errors[prefix.join("/")] = {
              actual: actual,
              expected: expected
            }
            false
          end

        else
          raise NotImplementedError, "#{expected} expectation is not supported"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :include_json do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    unless expected.is_a?(Hash)
      raise ArgumentError, "Expected value must be a json for include_json matcher"
    end

    RSpec::JsonExpectations::JsonTraverser.traverse(
      @include_json_errors = {},
      expected,
      JSON.parse(actual)
    )
  end

  # RSpec 2 vs 3
  send(respond_to?(:failure_message) ?
       :failure_message :
       :failure_message_for_should) do |actual|
         res = []

         @include_json_errors.each do |json_path, error|
           res << %{
           json atom on path "#{json_path}" is missing
           } if error == :no_key

           res << %{
           json atom on path "#{json_path}" is not equal to expected value:

             expected: #{error[:expected].inspect}
                  got: #{error[:actual].inspect}
           } if error.is_a?(Hash) && error.has_key?(:expected)
         end

         res.join("")
       end

end
```

It allows this syntax now:

```
        it "has basic info about user" do
          expect(subject).to include_json(
            id: 37,
            email: "john.smith@example.com",
            name: "Smith"
          )
        end
```

It generates errors like this:

```
  F

  Failures:

    1) A json response has basic info about user
       Failure/Error: expect(subject).to include_json(

                    json atom on path "id" is not equal to expected value:

                      expected: 37
                           got: 25

                    json atom on path "name" is not equal to expected value:

                      expected: "Smith"
                           got: "John"

       # ./spec/simple_with_fail_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  Finished in 0.00065 seconds
  1 example, 1 failure

  Failed examples:

  rspec ./spec/simple_with_fail_spec.rb:10 # A json response has basic info about user
```

Works for both RSpec 2 and 3.

If somebody interested it is here https://github.com/waterlink/rspec-json_expectations